# How I show all the marker in google map inside camera position flutter?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter

I am trying to mapView of my mobile screen like this. This view is showing on the web. Its camera position is covering all the markers. But On mobile, I am using google_map_flutter. I can't do this same view on mobile.

[image]

On mobile, the view looks like this. My zoom level is 0.

[image]

Here is my code in flutter

```
 cameraBounds = CameraTargetBounds(getBounds(bounds));
```

Here is my map container.

```
                          Container(
                                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-50,
                                 height: 400,
                                 child:  GoogleMap(
 
                                 zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                                 cameraTargetBounds: cameraBounds,
                                 zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                                 mapToolbarEnabled: true,
                                 gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<EagerGestureRecognizer>(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())),
                                 mapType: MapType.normal,
                                 tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
                                 scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                                 indoorViewEnabled: true,
                                 markers: this.myMarker(),
                                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                 initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                                 minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(0,13),
                                 onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                                    mapController = controller;
                                   _controller.complete(controller);
                                //  moveCamera();

                                 },
                               ),
                             )
```

Getting the markers bound.

```
  getBounds(List<LatLng> list) {

    //assert(list.isNotEmpty);
    print('Post size :' +list.length.toString());
    double x0, x1, y0, y1;
    if(list.isEmpty){
      return LatLngBounds(northeast: LatLng(0, 0), southwest: LatLng(0, 0));
    }else{
      for (LatLng latLng in list) {
        if (x0 == null) {
          x0 = x1 = latLng.latitude;
          y0 = y1 = latLng.longitude;
        } else {
          if (latLng.latitude > x1) x1 = latLng.latitude;
          if (latLng.latitude < x0) x0 = latLng.latitude;
          if (latLng.longitude > y1) y1 = latLng.longitude;
          if (latLng.longitude < y0) y0 = latLng.longitude;
        }
      }
      return LatLngBounds(northeast: LatLng(x1, y1), southwest: LatLng(x0, y0));
    }


  }
enter code here
```

I already tried with an animate camera or move camera but the view always looks like this. How I cover the whole map markers in one camera position. Please help me.